# Array operator (->) overload in nested call

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, inner-classes

I want to overload array opperator (->) as a standard operator for  pointers and additionaly whant to show somethink on the console.

And I did ...

**Gamer.h** file (**Gamer** class with nested **Collecion** class) :

```
class Gamer {

class Collection
{
public:
    Collection();
    Collection* operator->();
}
public:
Gamer();

Collection *deck;
}
```

**Gamer.cpp**

```
...
Gamer::Collection* Gamer::Collection::operator->()
{
    cout << "Pointer on deck >> " << this << endl;
    return this;
}
...
```

**main.cpp** - here i declare and alloc memory for Gamer object who have collection field inside (as pointer)

```
Gamer *gamer;

Gamer::allocGamer(gamer);
```

When i want to use overloaded array opperand I can't do :

```
gamer->deck->();
```

But I can :

```
gamer->deck->operator->();
```

The question is why I cant just call *gamer->deck->();* and have to call *gamer->deck->operator->();* instead ?

And second question - How I should overload arrow opperand to have direct access to overloaded opperand like *gamer->deck->();* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator->` is a binary operator. "binary operator" means it takes two operands. For example:

```
  deck -> foo
// ^        ^---- second operand
// |
// \------- first operand
```

It is not possible to write `deck->` without a second operand.

Calling it as `deck->operator->();` is a bit of a hack, which is legal but you should not design your code to rely on that because it will be confusing to readers.

The purpose of overloading `operator->` is so that you can write `deck->foo`. If you do not want to write `deck->foo` then you should not use `operator->` for whatever you are trying to do.

For example, if you just want a function to retrieve `foo` then call it `get_foo()` , not `operator->()`.

Note: `Gamer::allocGamer(gamer);` is suspicious (if `allocGamer` takes its parameter by value it's a bug, and if it takes it by reference then this is an unusual idiom that will be confusing to people reading your code).  Your code will be simpler if you don't use memory management, and don't force users of your class to use manual memory management either.

Comment: I know that i can make a getter but I have to do it throw arrow opperator. It is even possible ?

Comment: @PatrykJanik sorry I'm not sure what you are asking there

Comment: I cant edit my post. Instead of throw should be by.

I dont know the way how I should transform gamer->deck->operator->(); for gamer->deck->(); to call the opperand overloaded function.

Comment: So that's means when i should call for example gamer->deck->showCardCollection(); method first will be launched overloaded opperator function then showCardCollection() ? 
If yes I putted breakpoint into Gamer::Collection::operator->() and it even not entered into that function.

Comment: @PatrykJanik your code in the question is not a good example , the overloaded `operator->` will never be invoked for `deck->`.  because `deck` is a pointer. Like all overloaded operators (and indeed all member functions), It is invoked only when the left-hand side is an object of `Gamer` (not a pointer).   Using `->` on a pointer uses the built-in `->`, not an overloaded operator. For example `(*gamer->deck)->showCardCollection()` would invoke the operator.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself by using this complicated design;  to progress with your code it might be better if you start a new question explaining what you are trying to achieve at a higher level (and the solution will almost certainly not involve `operator->`).